# Keeping Property value on HTTP POST, and is Read only on view, in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to display a property as read only on a MVC view, and when the view is HTTP posted back, the property value remains, rather than null.

I tried the code, below but model binder return null,

```
@model Car

    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name); //need to be read only, but returns the value on HTTP POST

    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


 public ActionResult Index()
        {


            var car = new Car() {Name = "1"};
            return View(car);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Car car)  **//Name is NULL**
        {           
            return View(car);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
```

you can still put the `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)` on the page for display purposes.

Comment: Depends on what you want to display- the value of the model's property or the name of the property.  `@Html.LabelFor` is going to display, by default, the property name (e.g., "Name") unless you annotated the viewmodel with the `[DisplayName("Car Name")]` or whatever you want to display.  I think you want to show the value though, right?

Comment: Thanks. Is there alternative where one field is used instead of two. Because there are many properties to display.

Comment: Hmm.. well, you might be able to do something like this `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @readonly="readonly"})` and be able to display the Name property on the page and communicate it back on the post.  I haven't tried it though.  I believe that will work.  Worth a shot.